# Having a set of troubles in Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS / GNOME 42.5

Tags: boot, gnome, 22.04, brightness

Im having the following troubles and in need of help.

- At boot, it will show a black screen before coming to the login screen. then show the login screen twice (uneditable) and return to the black screen

- The solution currently using: boot from recovery > resume normal boot

- The brightness bar not showing and the keyboard keys are also not functioning

- This [video](https://youtu.be/WeMuvjgM2U0) but not working

My suspicion on how it came to this,
I tried to make windows glassy by watching a YT tutorial. It mentioned using material and mutter-rounded on git. The Matria part worked fine. but when installing mutter-rounded, when the package.sh is running, it could not run the `build-dep -y mutter` , saying it did not find the mutter source package. so I went to mutter index, downloaded the tar.xz file for gnome42.5, and manually installed using meson file in it + ninja command.
I tried repairing packages on recovery, and update, upgrade commands but, still no use.

Comment: Please note this is a Q&A site, not a user support forum. The aim is to collect questions and provide these with good answers, useful for future users. Therefore, typically one question should deal with a single topic.